# Check if file-input[] is empty

Tags: php, image, input

I have an `input type ="file"` in a `form` that upload images (multiple images) and other inputs (from textareas) .

I need that, if the user didn't choose any images, I don't want to excecute the upload image.
This because if I use the site from Ipad, the script give me error because he didn't find anything in the `file-input[]`, also if I don't want to upload images. 
So I wanna check if the `file-input[]` is `empty or not`, so the problem from Ipad will be solved (I hope).

This is the html

```
<div id="file-ins-immagini">
    <div class="et-form-ins">Immagini allegate</div>
    <input type="file" name="file-input[]" id="file-input" value="" class="file" multiple>  
</div>
```

And this is the code of the insert in php ('invia' is the name of the submit button of my form)

```
if (isset($_POST['invia']) && $_POST['invia'] == "Inserisci")  
{ 
    $messaggiocaso = "";
    $infoimages = array_combine($_FILES["file-input"]['name'], $_FILES["file-input"]['tmp_name']);  // recuperiamo e uniamo le informazionei sulle immagini 

    foreach ($infoimages as $k => $v)
    { 
        $nomefile = strtolower($k); 
        if(!empty($nomefile))
        {
            if (filesize($v) < $peso_file) 
            { 
                $estensionefile = pathinfo($nomefile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
                if (in_array(strtolower($estensionefile), $estensioni)) 
                {   
                    if (is_uploaded_file($v)) 
                    {      
                        if(!file_exists("$uploadDIR/$next_id"))  
                        {
                            mkdir("$uploadDIR/$next_id",0777,true); 
                        }

                        if (!move_uploaded_file($v, "$uploadDIR/$next_id/$nomefile")) 
                        { 
                            $messaggiocaso = urlencode("Impossibile l'inserimento del caso. Impossibile spostare il file $k");
                            header("location:tabella.php".'?msgcasoerrato='.$messaggiocaso);
                            exit;
                        } 
                        else 
                         //the rest of the code
```

I tryied with

```
if (isset($_POST['invia']) && $_POST['invia'] == "Inserisci" && !empty($_POST['file-input[]']))
```

and `!empty($_POST['file-input']`
but in these cases, the upload don't work anymore on pc.

So how can I check if file-input is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_FILES['file_input']){
  foreach($_FILES['file_input']['name'] as $k=>$v){
    if(!empty($_FILES['file_input']['name'][$k])){
       if($_FILES['file_input']['size'][$k]>0){
         // all ok, can be moved ..
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: trust me, i have rapidshare hosting

Comment: I used 
if '(isset($_POST['invia']) && $_POST['invia'] == "Inserisci" && !empty($_FILES['file_input']['name'])' and now it works. I didn't though to use $_FILE for the control. You're code suuggested me to do this :D so thank you. now works!